# std::span on Apple Clang can't be constructed

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang, c++20

I have a an object (which is passed as a const reference) to a function.
this object contains a `std::vector<unsigned short>`.
I want to generate a `std::span` of this vector within a range.
However, on Apple Clang, it refuses to do it:

Here is a snippet that resembles my code. It compiles fine on Godbolt:

```cpp
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
struct level_state {
    std::vector<unsigned short> floor_datas;
};

struct room_info {
    std::vector<std::size_t> floor;
};

unsigned short get_floor_data_count(const unsigned short header) {
    return header & 0x3FFF;
}

std::span<const unsigned short> get_floor_data(const level_state& level, const room_info& room, const std::size_t sector_offset) {
    const std::size_t offset = room.floor[sector_offset];
    const auto header = level.floor_datas[offset];
    auto span = std::span(level.floor_datas.begin() + offset, level.floor_datas.begin() + offset + get_floor_data_count(header));
    //assert_postcondition(((*(span.rbegin())) & 0x3FF) == 0x3FF, "Floor Data does not end with 0x3FFF");
    return span;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/a3GnT69jG

I receive the following error(s):

```
[build] /.../floor_data.cpp:229:64: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::span<const unsigned short, std::dynamic_extent>'
[build]                         std::span<const unsigned short, std::dynamic_extent> span = std::span<const unsigned short, std::dynamic_extent>(level.floor_datas.begin() + offset,
[build]                                                                                     ^                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:405:41: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__wrap_iter<const unsigned short *>' to 'std::span<const unsigned short, 18446744073709551615>::pointer' (aka 'const unsigned short *') for 1st argument
[build]     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr span(pointer __ptr, size_type __count) : __data{__ptr}, __size{__count} {}
[build]                                         ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:406:41: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__wrap_iter<const unsigned short *>' to 'std::span<const unsigned short, 18446744073709551615>::pointer' (aka 'const unsigned short *') for 1st argument
[build]     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr span(pointer __f, pointer __l) : __data{__f}, __size{static_cast<size_t>(distance(__f, __l))} {}
[build]                                         ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:424:19: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '__is_span_compatible_container<std::__wrap_iter<const unsigned short *>, const unsigned short, void>::value' was not satisfied [with _Container = std::__wrap_iter<const unsigned short *>]
[build]         constexpr span(      _Container& __c,
[build]                   ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:430:19: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '__is_span_compatible_container<const std::__wrap_iter<const unsigned short *>, const unsigned short, void>::value' was not satisfied [with _Container = std::__wrap_iter<const unsigned short *>]
[build]         constexpr span(const _Container& __c,
[build]                   ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:437:19: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'span' against '__wrap_iter'
[build]         constexpr span(const span<_OtherElementType, _OtherExtent>& __other,
[build]                   ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:402:15: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
[build]     constexpr span           (const span&) noexcept = default;
[build]               ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:410:15: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__arr', but 2 arguments were provided
[build]     constexpr span(element_type (&__arr)[_Sz])          noexcept : __data{__arr}, __size{_Sz} {}
[build]               ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:415:15: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__arr', but 2 arguments were provided
[build]     constexpr span(array<_OtherElementType, _Sz>& __arr) noexcept : __data{__arr.data()}, __size{_Sz} {}
[build]               ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:420:15: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__arr', but 2 arguments were provided
[build]     constexpr span(const array<_OtherElementType, _Sz>& __arr) noexcept : __data{__arr.data()}, __size{_Sz} {}
[build]               ^
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/span:400:41: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
[build]     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr span() noexcept : __data{nullptr}, __size{0} {}
[build]                                         ^
[build] 1 error generated.
```

To me, it looks like the iterator constructor is missing?

Comment: DId you specify the language standard? See https://godbolt.org/z/xPY7sf38r, I had to tell the compiler to use C++20. `-std=c++20` and then it compiles (clang version 14)

Comment: You can recreate it on godbolt by specifying `-stdlib=libc++`. Seems it uses libstdc++ by default.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Are you sure? Still compiled for me https://godbolt.org/z/vdbnTeW6G even with libc++ (or did I miss something?)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Apple Clang is based on Clang 13. I get the exact same errors on godbolt when using Clang 13 and stdlib=libc++.
I used the pointer/pointer constructor as an immediate solution.

Comment: @PepijnKramer - You missed the compiler version the OP used

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica can you make an answer?

Comment: I only pointed out the library usage for the example. It's not exactly an answer. If you investigated further and have an answer now, you can post it yourself.

Comment: does not seem to work even in upstream clang / libc++ 14 : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bK1xEhbdM